# Trying to get double value from a csv file, consistently getting NULL in C

Tags: c, csv

I need to get a `double` value for my `Movie` struct. So my assignment is that I read from a csv file, (It will be provided) and output certain information like what movies come in this language, or what movies come out in this year, or the highest rated movies in said year. Anyways. The problem I am having is that when I have my "token" try and retrieve the value it returns as NULL.

**Main.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct movie
{
    char *title;
    int year;
    char **lang;
    int numLang; // New variable to store the number of languages
    double ratingValue;
    struct movie *next;
};

/* Parse the curr line which is "," broken and create a movie struct with the data in curr line
*/
struct movie *createMovie(char *currLine)
{
    struct movie *currMovie = malloc(sizeof(struct movie));
    char *ptr;

    // title
    char *token = strtok_r(currLine, ",", &ptr);
    currMovie->title = calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(currMovie->title, token);

    // year
    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
    currMovie->year = atoi(token);

    // language
    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
    token = strtok_r(token, "[];", &ptr);
    currMovie->lang = NULL; // Initialize to NULL
    int numLang = 0; // Initialize numLang
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        currMovie->lang = realloc(currMovie->lang, (numLang + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        currMovie->lang[numLang] = calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(currMovie->lang[numLang], token);
        numLang++;
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "[];", &ptr);
    }

    // Set numLang for the current movie
    currMovie->numLang = numLang;

    // rating value
    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &ptr);
    if (token != NULL)  // Check if token is not NULL
    {
        // Use sscanf to directly extract the rating value as a float
        if (sscanf(token, "%lf", &currMovie->ratingValue) != 1)
        {
            // Handle the case where the conversion fails
            currMovie->ratingValue = 0.0;
            printf("Token: \"%s\". Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).\n", token);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the rating value is missing or invalid
        // For example, set it to a default value or display an error message.
        currMovie->ratingValue = 0.0;
        printf("Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).\n");
    }

    // Set the next node to NULL
    currMovie->next = NULL;

    return currMovie;
}

/*
* Return linked list of movies by parsing data from each line
*/
struct movie *processFile(char *filePath)
{
    // open file
    FILE *movieFile = fopen(filePath, "r");

    char *currLine = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t nread;

    struct movie *head = NULL;
    struct movie *tail = NULL;

    // read file
    while ((nread = getline(&currLine, &len, movieFile)) != -1)
    {
        // Get new movie
        struct movie *newNode = createMovie(currLine);

        // Skip the header line
        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // id first node
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            // first node in the linked link, Set head and tail to node
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }
    free(currLine);
    fclose(movieFile);
    return head;
}
```

Small portion from .csv file

```
Title,Year,Languages,Rating Value
The Incredible Hulk,2008,[English;Portuguese;Spanish],6.8
Sherlock Holmes,2009,[English;French],7.6
Iron Man,2008,[English;Persian;Urdu;Arabic;Hungarian],7.9
Iron Man 2,2010,[English;French;Russian],7.2
Iron Man 3,2013,[English],7.2
Thor: Ragnarok,2017,[English],7.9
The Avengers,2012,[English;Russian;Hindi],8.1
Doctor Strange,2016,[English],7.5
Avengers: Infinity War,2018,[English],8.5
Avengers: Age of Ultron,2015,[English;Korean],7.4
Thor,2011,[English],7
Thor: The Dark World,2013,[English],7
```

As you can see in the csv file after "Rating Value" it moves onto the new line. The issue is that I need to retrieve the "rating value" when I am making my "List" of movies. I am compiling using `--std=gnu99` This is a system requirement. I need the double value from that and would appreciate any help I can get.

Edit this is my output

```
flip3 ~/os1 998$ ./movies movies_sample_1.csv
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).
Token is NULL. Invalid or missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).

1. Show movies released in the specified year
2. Show highest rated movie for each year
3. Show the title and year of release of all movies in a specific language
4. Exit from the program

Enter a choice from 1 to 4: 1
Enter the year for which you want to see movies: 2008
The Incredible Hulk
Iron Man

1. Show movies released in the specified year
2. Show highest rated movie for each year
3. Show the title and year of release of all movies in a specific language
4. Exit from the program

Enter a choice from 1 to 4: 2

Highest rated movie for each year:
0 0.0 Title
2008 0.0 The Incredible Hulk
2009 0.0 Sherlock Holmes
2010 0.0 Iron Man 2
2013 0.0 Iron Man 3
2017 0.0 Thor: Ragnarok
2012 0.0 The Avengers
2016 0.0 Doctor Strange
2018 0.0 Avengers: Infinity War
2015 0.0 Avengers: Age of Ultron
2011 0.0 Thor
2014 0.0 Captain America: The Winter Soldier
2003 0.0 Right on Track

1. Show movies released in the specified year
2. Show highest rated movie for each year
3. Show the title and year of release of all movies in a specific language
4. Exit from the program

Enter a choice from 1 to 4: 3
Enter the language for which you want to see movies: English
2008 The Incredible Hulk
2009 Sherlock Holmes
2008 Iron Man
2010 Iron Man 2
2013 Iron Man 3
2017 Thor: Ragnarok
2012 The Avengers
2016 Doctor Strange
2018 Avengers: Infinity War
2015 Avengers: Age of Ultron
2011 Thor
2013 Thor: The Dark World
2017 Spider-Man: Homecoming
2011 Captain America: The First Avenger
2016 Captain America: Civil War
2015 Ant-Man
2014 Captain America: The Winter Soldier
2018 Mary Queen of Scots
2016 Revolting Rhymes Part One
2017 The Glass Castle
2016 Free Fire
2003 Right on Track
2012 Rise of the Guardians
2012 Anna Karenina

1. Show movies released in the specified year
2. Show highest rated movie for each year
3. Show the title and year of release of all movies in a specific language
4. Exit from the program

Enter a choice from 1 to 4: 4
Exiting the program
```

Comment: Be aware that you can replace the calloc/strcpy calls with a single call to strdup.

Comment: I have spotted one problem, but I don't know if it's the problem you ask about. So please [edit] your question to tell us the output of the code you show, what is really printed?

Comment: When you have read the language "array", what's left in the string will be ",6.8" (for example). You don't handle that comma, which will lead the scanf call to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- You use the same state pointer `ptr` to parse tokens from the languages fields and for the enclosing line.  You should use 2 separate state pointers. This explains the behavior reported.
- use `strdup` to allocate copies of character strings.  This is just a simplification.
- The type for `nread` should be `ssize_t`.
- To skip the header line, just read and discard the first line in the file.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct movie {
    char *title;
    int year;
    char **lang;
    int numLang; // New variable to store the number of languages
    double ratingValue;
    struct movie *next;
};

/* Parse the curr line which is "," broken and create a movie struct with the data in curr line
 */
struct movie *createMovie(char *currLine)
{
    struct movie *currMovie = malloc(sizeof(struct movie));
    if (!currMovie)
        return NULL;

    char *ptr;
    // title
    char *token = strtok_r(currLine, ",", &ptr);
    currMovie->title = strdup(token ? token : "");

    // year
    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
    currMovie->year = token ? atoi(token) : 0;

    // language
    currMovie->lang = NULL;
    currMovie->numLang = 0;

    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
    if (token) {
        int numLang = 0;
        char *ptr1;
        token = strtok_r(token, "[];", &ptr1);
        while (token != NULL) {
            currMovie->lang = realloc(currMovie->lang, (numLang + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            if (currMovie->lang == NULL)
                break;
            currMovie->lang[numLang] = strdup(token);
            currMovie->numLang++;
            numLang++;
            token = strtok_r(NULL, "[];", &ptr1);
        }
    }

    // rating value
    token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &ptr);
    if (token) {
        if (sscanf(token, "%lf", &currMovie->ratingValue) != 1) {
            currMovie->ratingValue = 0.0;
            printf("Token: \"%s\". Invalid rating value. Setting to default (0.0).\n", token);
        }
    } else {
        currMovie->ratingValue = 0.0;
        printf("Missing rating value. Setting to default (0.0).\n");
    }
    currMovie->next = NULL;
    return currMovie;
}

/*
 * Return linked list of movies by parsing data from each line
 */
struct movie *processFile(const char *filePath)
{
    // open file
    FILE *movieFile = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (movieFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filePath, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    char *currLine = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    struct movie *head = NULL;
    struct movie *tail = NULL;

    // skip the header line
    getline(&currLine, &len, movieFile);

    // read file
    while ((nread = getline(&currLine, &len, movieFile)) >= 0)
    {
        // Get new movie
        struct movie *newNode = createMovie(currLine);

        if (newNode == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // id first node
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            // first node in the linked link, Set head and tail to node
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }
    free(currLine);
    fclose(movieFile);
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are running 2 strtok_r sequences but using the same pointer.

Change to do this

```
   char* ptr;
   char* ptr1;

// language
token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
token = strtok_r(token, "[];", &ptr1);
    
     ...
     token = strtok_r(NULL, "[];", &ptr1);
```

ie when scanning the token returned by the third ',' scan use a new pointer

Answer (score 0):

This is your data in the provided code

```
struct movie
{
    char *title;
    int year;
    char **lang;
    int numLang; // New variable to store the number of languages
    double ratingValue;
    struct movie *next;
};
```

Sure, you can get it done this way, but:

- it is too much complex. The abstraction is really far from reality
- the code will the hard to read
- even harder to extend
- almost impossible to reuse

Consider what in fact you are trying to do

**Build a linked list of movies, loaded from a simple *csv* file.**

But in your model:

- there is no linked list
- there is no node
- there is no data record
- the data is buried inside a `struct` that is also a node of a list and is used if it was in fact a linked list

A **linked list** is an abstract data structure. A (possibly empty) collection of nodes, something any book on DS would tell you.
A **node** is the unit content of the list. It points to or contains a data record.
A `data record` in your case describes a movie.

Do not mix the list with its contents.

See this, from the orginal code:

```
struct movie *processFile(char *filePath)
{
    // open file
    FILE *movieFile = fopen(filePath, "r");

    char *currLine = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t nread;

    struct movie *head = NULL;
    struct movie *tail = NULL;
    //...
```

These pointers are lost inside the code, but in fact they are pointers for the same list. `len` maybe the size of the list. **Encapsulation** is a powerful concept: this pointers must be inside each list they point to. They are called *metadata* and are part of the list, as its size also is. BTOH, their meaning has nothing to do with `struct movie`.

### A simple model

#### a data  record in `my_data.h`

```
typedef struct
{
   char*  title;
   char   year[5]; // more practical as a string
   size_t n_lang;  // non-negative
   char** lang;    // could be another linked list
   double rating;  // no need for suffix

} Movie;
```

#### A Node in `my_list.h`

A node here is just it: a link, containing a pointer to some `Info` thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_data.h"

typedef Movie Info;

typedef struct node_
{
    Info*         data;
    struct node_* next;
} Node;  // a node

int so_print_node(Node*, const char* msg);
```

But the `typedef` links `Info` to the `Movie` we have now, so if we need to use a list elsewhere we can just change this line and the obvious `include`

`so_print_node()` just displays a node on screen, and acceps an optional message. It is called when we print a list, so it is easy to adapt to lists of anything.

In fact a more generic approach would be to pass pointers to some operations on nodes rigth on the creation of the list, but may be too much to do here.

#### A List  in `my_list.h`

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* so_create_l();
List* so_delete_l(List*);
int   so_insert_back(const Info*, List*);
int   so_insert_front(const Info*, List*);
int   so_print_l(List*, const char* msg);
```

Here we have a list and some obvious operations. Note that there is no mention to `Movie` here: `List` is just a *container* of nodes.

### Consuming the `input.csv` file

Note that the *csv* file has no relationship with the linked list. The use of the list is just an implementation detail and you should not mix the 2 in development.

#### an example

Let's extend `my_data.h` with a few operations on `Movie`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char*  title;
    char   year[5];  // more practical as a string
    size_t n_lang;   // non-negative
    char** lang;     // could be another linked list
    double rating;   // no need for suffix

} Movie;

Movie* delete_movie(Movie*);
Movie* from_line(const char*);
int    show_movie(Movie*, const char*);
```

These are obvious, the minimum to consume the input file

#### the implementation in `my_data.c`

```
#include "my_data.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Movie* from_line(const char* line)
{
    if (line == NULL) return NULL;
    char title[101];
    char year[6];
    char lang[101];
    char rating[11];
    int  res = sscanf(
        line, "%100[^,],%5[^,],%100[^,],%10[^,]", title,
        year, lang, rating);
    // printf("sscanf() returned %d\n", res);
    if (res != 4) return NULL;
    Movie* movie = malloc(sizeof(Movie));  // a new movie
    movie->title = malloc(1 + strlen(title));
    strcpy(movie->title, title);
    strcpy(movie->year, year);
    movie->n_lang = 0;
    movie->lang   = NULL;
    movie->rating = atof(rating);
    return movie;
}

int show_movie(Movie* M, const char* msg)
{
    if (M == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
    %5.2f %5s %s\n",
        M->rating, M->year, M->title);
    return 0;
}

Movie* delete_movie(Movie* M)
{
    if (M == NULL) return NULL;
    free(M->title);
    if (M->lang != NULL)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < M->n_lang; i += 1)
            free(M->lang[i]);
    free(M);
    return NULL;
}
```

#### `main` for a test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "my_data.h"

int load_file(const char*);
void   usage();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[80] = {0};
    if (argc < 2) usage();
    return load_file(argv[1]);
};

int load_file(const char* f_name)
{
    if (f_name == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(stderr, "*****loading \"%s\"\n\n", f_name);
    FILE* F = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (F == NULL) return -2;
    // file is open
    size_t n_lines = 0;
    char   line[200];
    char*  p = &line[0];
    p        = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F); // skips header line
    p        = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        ++n_lines;
        //fprintf(stderr, "  #%llu:\t%s", n_lines,p);
        Movie* movie = from_line(p);
        if (movie != NULL)
        {
            show_movie(movie, NULL);
            delete_movie(movie);
        }
        p = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    };  // while()
    fclose(F);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\n***** %llu lines read\n", n_lines);
    return 0;
}

void usage()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Use: program file_to_load\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

#### `input.csv` for a test

```
Title,Year,Languages,Rating Value
The Incredible Hulk,2008,[English;Portuguese;Spanish],6.8
Sherlock Holmes,2009,[English;French],7.6
Iron Man,2008,[English;Persian;Urdu;Arabic;Hungarian],7.9
Iron Man 2,2010,[English;French;Russian],7.2
Iron Man 3,2013,[English],7.2
Thor: Ragnarok,2017,[English],7.9
The Avengers,2012,[English;Russian;Hindi],8.1
Doctor Strange,2016,[English],7.5
Avengers: Infinity War,2018,[English],8.5
Avengers: Age of Ultron,2015,[English;Korean],7.4
Thor,2011,[English],7
Thor: The Dark World,2013,[English],7
```

#### output of the test

```
Stack Overflow >read_csv input.csv
*****loading "input.csv"

     6.80  2008 The Incredible Hulk
     7.60  2009 Sherlock Holmes
     7.90  2008 Iron Man
     7.20  2010 Iron Man 2
     7.20  2013 Iron Man 3
     7.90  2017 Thor: Ragnarok
     8.10  2012 The Avengers
     7.50  2016 Doctor Strange
     8.50  2018 Avengers: Infinity War
     7.40  2015 Avengers: Age of Ultron
     7.00  2011 Thor
     7.00  2013 Thor: The Dark World


***** 12 lines read

Stack Overflow >
```

And we see the rating, year and title for each movie.

#### to go on from here

Now we have code to consume and convert the data. It is just a matter of converting the languages to an array of strings in `from_line()` and call the required functions to insert the data as nodes in a linked list.

Not mixing it all.